# What are Marshal Slices?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, timer, marshalling

What are Marshal Slices? And what are they used for?
I have looked up over the internet and found a couple of articles stating use of Marshal Slices but I still don't understand what are they.

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/) by the person who created the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ted Patrick coined the term "The Elastic Racetrack" he proposed the AVM2 is controlled by something called the Marshal.

The elastic racetrack is all about frames and the **time** given to each frame and the marshal is responsible for carving out these time slices, the duration of one of these slices varies depending on operating software and browser.

Understanding the relationship between the elastic racetrack and flex lifecycle gives much greater clarity on this concept.

[image]

Comment: this presentation does a fine job at illustrating the marshal slice http://www.slideshare.net/mrinalwadhwa/flex-4-component-lifecycle